# Best_in_place, activating multiple fields

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I am using [best_in_place](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing?view=asciicast) in my rails app, here is its [git](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place). I am trying to add activator attribute to it, I have gone through these questions: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767383/rails-best-in-place-jquery-in-place-editing-activator-button-not-working) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113045/rails-best-in-place-gem-while-clicking-on-the-label-name) and it works fine. but I want to activate two fields with same activator. my view looks like:

```
 <%=best_in_place @new_thread, :title, :html_attrs => {:id => 'new_thread_title'},:activator => ".activator"%>

<%= best_in_place @new_thread, :description, type: :textarea, :html_attrs => {:id => 'new_thread_description'}, :activator => ".activator" %>
```

and my activator button is:

```
<a href="#" class="activator">Edit</a>
```

but when I click on edit only description(textarea) is activated for edit. I want both title and description to be activated. Any kind of insight on the problem is welcome.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Sorry Asnad. I had to use two different activators.

Comment: no problem thanks for your reply